# How to parse child node value of an xml through kissxml parser?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml file:

```
<Menu>
<item value="boiled">
    <image value="boiling1recipe">boiling1.jpg</image>
    <recipeImage>png1.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png2.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png3.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png4.png</recipeImage>
  </item>
  <item value="boiled">
    <image value="boiling2recipe">boiling2.jpeg</image>
    <recipeImage>png5.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png6.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png7.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png8.png</recipeImage>
  </item>
  <item value="rosted">
    <image value="roasted1recipe">roasted1.jpeg</image>
    <recipeImage>png8.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png9.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png10.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png11.png</recipeImage>
   </item>
  <item value="rosted">
    <image value="roasted2recipe">roasted2.jpeg</image>
    <recipeImage>png12.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png13.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png1.png</recipeImage>
    <recipeImage>png2.png</recipeImage>
   </item>
</Menu>
```

Now,
I am parsing it like this:

```
    DDXMLNode *node = [item attributeForName:@"value"];

    if ([[node stringValue] isEqual:@"boiled"]) {
        [listOfBoiledItems addObject:model];

        DDXMLNode *node1 = [item attributeForName:@"value"];

        if ([[node1 stringValue] isEqual:@"boiling1recipe"]) {
            [listOfRecipies1 addObject:model];
        }
        else if ([[node1 stringValue] isEqual:@"boiling2recipe"]) { 
            [listOfRecipies2 addObject:model];
        }
     }
            else if ([[node stringValue] isEqual:@"rosted"]) {  
        [listOfRostedItems addObject:model];

        DDXMLNode *node1 = [item attributeForName:@"value"];

        if ([[node1 stringValue] isEqual:@"roasted1recipe"]) {  
            [listOfRecipies6 addObject:model];
        }
        else if ([[node1 stringValue] isEqual:@"roasted2recipe"]) {
            [listOfRecipies7 addObject:model];
        }
    }
```

Here,
compiler reading the parent node value i.e. "boiled" and "rosted" but not reading the chile node value i.e. "boiling1recipe", "boiling2recipe", "roasted1recipe" and "roasted2recipe".
What may be the problem, means Am I doing something wrong ?
Please guide me as its my first time to do parsing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you go with an XPath query instead? This would be easier and you could parse every single item in a loop.
I didn't try this code on your XML but it should work:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *xmlItems = [ddDoc nodesForXPath:@"//item" error:&error]; // where ddDoc is your DDXMLDocument

for(DDXMLElement* itemElement in xmlItems)
{
    // Here you get the item->value attribute value as string...
    NSString *itemValueAsString = [[itemElement attributeForName:@"value"]stringValue];

    // Now you get the image element from inside the item element
    DDXMLElement *imageElement = [[itemElement nodesForXPath:@"image" error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];

    // And finally the image->value attribute value as string…
    NSString *imageValueAsString = [[imageElement attributeForName:@"value"]stringValue];
}
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Need to release the string ?